# Extension method to check if an instance is null

Tags: c#

To check to see if an object is null you can do either:

```
var myObject = DoSomeCallThatMayReturnNull();
var myString = string.Empty;
```

.

```
if (myObject == null)
  myString = "null";
```

**-- OR --**

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, myObject)) 
   myString = "null";
```

and in some circumstances use the null coallescing operator ??. What I would like to do however is to add an extension method of IsNull so that I can do things like:

```
if (myObject.IsNull())
```

and for nullable types such as int? also be able to do:

```
if (myInt.IsNull())
```

My naive implementation is:

```
public static bool IsNull(this Object aObject)
{
    return aObject == null;
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: I think your naive implementation should work just fine :p

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, yes, but nothing prevents calling it on a value type, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque interesting... I was thinking all types that can be cast to object would have to be reference types but I'll take your word for it. Agreed that it adds no value.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, every type in .NET inherits from Object, including value types. If you pass a value type to a method that expects an Object, it will be [boxed (see MSDN for details)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would implement it like this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNull<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        return obj == null;
    }

    public static bool IsNull<T>(this T? obj) where T : struct
    {
        return !obj.HasValue;
    }
}
```

This way, it can't be called on value types (which are never null), except nullable value types.

However I'm not convinced of the usefulness of that method... Just comparing with null is just as readable.

Comment: To me the usefulness comes in that a) I don't need to know whether it is a value type or an object and hence use different syntax to determine whether the object I am looking at "is nul". So I can always do varName.IsNull() instead of (varName == null || varName.HasValue )

Comment: @TheEdge, you don't need to check `(varName == null || varName.HasValue )`, it's redundant. Nullables are structs, so they're never *really* null... `varName.HasValue` will work even on a "null" nullable, and will give the same result as `varName == null`.

Comment: As soon as this extension is outside of your compilation unit (different dll) it can't be inlined, and you have a 100% function call on your hands. This will be a huge it in a loop.

Comment: @PasiSavolainen are you sure about that? Inlining is done by the JIT, and I don't think it cares if the method belongs to a different assembly.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you are correct! Measured it (inliner diagnostic) and it does get inlined cross-dll: https://github.com/pasisavolainen/Teshtink Sorry for FUD.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation would work. Additionally, if you wanted something similar for value types you could do:

```
public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this object source) where T : struct 
{
    return source == null || source.Equals(default (T));
}
```

Comment: `default(T)` is null, where possible.  So this is redundant.

Comment: What's the point? A value type will be boxed into the object here.. which means it will never be null and never the default (unless you do `0.IsNullOrDefault()`)..

Comment: I think I misunderstand default's relation to null then. I'm going to leave this up while I go learn up in case I have a question.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil Explanation: Your function is wrong in two ways. Firstly, `default(T)` for reference types is `null`. So having a `null` check and `default(T)` is redundant.. you only need one. Secondly, your "similar for value types" comment is redundant.. because a value type passed into this method will be boxed to an object.. and therefore never `null`. However, it will be `default` if you try it on a value type with the default value.. e.g: `int == 0`, `float == 0f`, etc.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks for the explanation. I meant to include the struct constraint in my original answer. I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around this (long day). I wrote out some code that confuses me more. I'm about to head home so I'll create a new question when I get to the house (would like to get your explanation after I show you the code that's throwing me off).